# Tag removal request

Tags: support, retag-request

The following tags are have wikis submitted but aren't valuable imo - each have only one question:

[catalina](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/catalina) - a tomcat startup script, the tomcat tag is sufficient

[aafp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aafp) - a connector on Asus motherboards

[fontforge](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fontforge) - a website dealing with fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go ahead and remove them from the questions. Giving a reason why in the edit summary is preferred.

As a 10k user, we trust you to look over the newly created tags yourself. Simply go to:

https://superuser.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last30days

… and look at the newest tags on the bottom:

> [image]

Chances are you'll find some that need to be removed before people use them more frequently. [shopping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shopping) and [nuevi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nuevi) come to mind, for example.

Once they are removed from the last question, they will be auto-deleted after a while if they haven't been used subsequently.

Comment: Does removing them from the questions remove them altogether if they are on no questions as a result?

Comment: Yes, they will be auto-deleted after 30 days (IIRC) and can only be recreated by users [with appropriate permissions](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Of course, that doesn't stop users from creating them altogether—to prevent that we'd have to have the tags blacklisted by a developer, but this isn't done often.